# TensorFlow wide and deep example error

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow

I`d like to build a binary classfier basing on the the wide-and-deep Tensorflow tutorial [(here is its "Main" file this question is referring to)](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/wide_deep/wide_deep.py).

As a first step I am running the default example as-is and using it to familiarize with TF before adapting it to my needs.

I am encountering a problem running it. In line 199 of the aforementioned file I have to substitute

`tensors_to_log={'average_loss': loss_prefix + 'head/truediv',
'loss': loss_prefix + 'head/weighted_loss/Sum'})`

with

```
tensors_to_log={'average_loss': loss_prefix + 'head/weighted_loss/Sum'})
```

otherwise I get the following error:

```
KeyError: "The name 'head/truediv:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'head/truediv', does not exist in the graph."
```

IDE is PyCharm, OS is Ubunty 16.04LTS, Tensorflow version is 1.5.0rc1 (not newer due to compatibility issues with my cpu from 2007)

What may be causing this / how may I fix the root of this problem?

Is the code change I did as a workaround impacting on the quality of the results / saved model or just on the quality of the logging?

Comment: That code relies on features external to TensorFlow. The `hooks_helper` stuff is helpful but unnecessary. You should be able to delete the `train_hooks` variable and remove the argument from `model.train`. Will that work?

Comment: I removed part of it already, good to know that it is not necessary for the model itself to run well. I'll look into removing it all together. Thankyou - you should make and answe out of your comment

Comment: got same error here and when I remove code with ```train_hooks```, it runs well.

Answer (score 2):

submit an issue and give code removing example here: 
[github of tensorflow model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3959)
It should have more answers about why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

(Copied from the github issue created by Canoe)

The master version of the repo works with the tensorflow nightly build. If you are running an older version of tensorflow, I would recommend checking out the [r1.5 branch](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/r1.5/official) or one of the releases: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/releases